# Sencha Touch + Brightcove player

Tags: node.js, extjs, brightcove

Anyone have any experience getting Brightcove's SmartPlayer embed-code ( tag) to work inside a Sencha Touch panel? It wont show up for some reason. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use http://opensource.brightcove.com/project/JavaScript-MAPI-Wrapper/ instead to embed BC SmartPlayer code. I've develop an app some months ago and that approach didn't work

Hope you help